# Detecting parent object when calling JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have an object, i.e.:

```
{
  item1: "value1",
  item2: "value2",
  item3: { 
      item4: "value4",
      item5: "value5" 
  }
}
```

I want to use `JSON.stringify` with a `replacer` function that will **act different on items 4 & 5**, the inner properties of item3.

How can that be done ?

something like the following **pseudo-code:**

```
     return JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
         if (key is child of Item3) {
             return someOtherValue;
         } else {
             return val; 
         } 
}
```

The desired output is json. i.e.:

```
{ 
  "item1" : "value1", 
  "item2" : "value2", 
  "item3" : { 
      "item4" : "theSomeOtherValue", 
      "item5" : "theSomeOtherValue"
}
```

**Edit**:
Items 4 & 5 are not known beforehand, they are dynamically generated.
I only know the title for `item3` at run time

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: the desired output is json. i.e.: `{ "item1" : "value1", "item2" : "value2", "item3" : { "item4" : "theSomeOtherValue", "item5" : "theSomeOtherValue" }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two approaches you can take here.

1. In the replacer function, `this` is the object being processed, so when `item4` and `item5` are being processed, `this` refers to the `item3` object. So if there's anything about that object that lets you identify it, you can do that by looking at `this`. (Be sure to use a traditional function, not an arrow functions, so that `JSON.stringify` can set what `this` is during the replacer call.)
2. The replacer function is called with the key and value being processed, so if the key of the object (`"item3"`) is unique, you could do special processing when you see it.

Here are a couple of examples of #1:

For instance, if you have a reference to the object, you can compare `this` to `obj.item3`:

```js
const obj = {
    item1: "value1",
    item2: "value2",
    item3: { 
        item4: "value4",
        item5: "value5" 
    }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
//                              ^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Traditional function, not arrow function
    if (this === obj.item3) {
        console.log("do something different, it's " + key);
        return "theSomeOtherValue";
    }
    return value;
}));
```

If you don't have a reference to it, you can use any other identifying information you have about it. For instance, with the example data, you can see that it has `item4` and `item5` properties:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
    item1: "value1",
    item2: "value2",
    item3: { 
        item4: "value4",
        item5: "value5" 
    }
}, function(key, value) {
// ^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Traditional function, not arrow function
    if (this.hasOwnProperty("item4") && this.hasOwnProperty("item5")) {
        console.log("do something different, it's " + key);
        return "theSomeOtherValue";
    }
    return value;
}));
```

Those are just two examples, though; the key thing is that `this` is the object being stringified.

Here's an example of #2:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
    item1: "value1",
    item2: "value2",
    item3: { 
        item4: "value4",
        item5: "value5" 
    }
}, (key, value) => { // It's okay if this one is an arrow function, we're not relying on
                     // `JSON.stringify` setting `this` for us
    if (key === "item3") {
        return {
            item4: "theSomeOtherValue",
            item5: "theSomeOtherValue"
        };
    }
    return value;
}));
```

If you need the full path of the object being processed, that's a bit more of a pain, but you can get it:

```js
let paths = new Map();
console.log(JSON.stringify({
    item1: "value1",
    item2: "value2",
    item3: { 
        item4: "value4",
        item5: "value5" 
    },
    item6: {
        item3: {
            item4: "non-special item4",
            item5: "non-special item5"
        }
    }
}, function(key, value) {
// ^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Traditional function, not arrow function
    const path = paths.get(this);
    // Special processing for the properties of root.item3
    if (path === "root.item3") {
        return key === "item4" || key === "item5"
            ? "theSomeOtherValue"
            : value;
    }

    // Keep track of the path of the object
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(this)) {
        if (typeof v === "object") {
            if (path) {
                // The regex checks for property names that aren't valid(ish)
                // property names so we can use brackets notation
                paths.set(v, path + (/^\w+$/.test(k) ? "." + k : `[${JSON.stringify(k)}]`));
            } else {
                paths.set(v, "root");
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) accepts a replacer function as 2nd argument (and provides the current object being iterated as `this`) so you can do:

```
return JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
    if (this === obj.item3) {
        return "theSomeOtherValue";
    }
    return val;
});
```

Another way to achieve the same (using current `key` instead of `this` object reference):

```
return JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
    if (key === "item4" || key === "item5") {
        return "theSomeOtherValue";
    }
    return val;
});
```

Comment: This answer has already been posted, several minutes ago. Please check for previous answers before answering, so you don't just repost answers that have been given.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the found wanted object in a closure and change the return value depening on the object.

This approach works **without** `this`.

```js
function replacer(parent) {
    let reference = {};
    return function (key, val) {
        if (key === parent) reference = val;
        return key in reference
            ? '#' + val
            : val; 
    };
}

var obj = { item1: "value1", item2: "value2", item3: { item4: "value4", item5: "value5" } },
    json = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer('item3'));

console.log(json);
```